# What is the actual meaning of render method in asp.net basic life cycle?

Tags: asp.net, render, page-lifecycle

I have read many articles explaining ASP.NET page life cycle but I found really confusing results about render method in ASP.NET page life cycle. I am at a basic level and I just want to know the simplest meaning and working of the render method.

Comment: Your question is probably too broad. Please, consider editing it: which part do you find confusing?

Comment: if you're talking about asp.net webpages I wouldn't use it anymore. try to focus on aps.net core (mvc, razor pages, blazor, web api)

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.Net WebForms, most of the time you are working against an object model (Label controls, TextBox controls, Repeaters, ...). However, the browser wants to get HTML.

The job of the Render phase is to translate the control-tree into a single HTML text, which then gets sent to the browser.

If you are a beginner, you shouldn't need to do anything special here.